# Plot HH:MM:SS formatted data in R, when HH goes above 24

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data set (tt) that consists of values like these:

```
"76:12:49" "74:11:32" "62:39:26" "57:17:17" "43:10:59" "29:06:00" "21:32:30" "16:00:36" "13:31:27" " 9:55:12" " 9:30:34"
```

I can't seem to come up with a way of plotting these values.  Zoo/chron combo doesn't work because times(tt) can't process anything with an HH above 23.

I'm assuming ggplot's time plotting capabilities won't work here either, since strptime similarly won't work on anything with HH above 23.

Any ideas?

Comment: In your case, these are more timespan than timestamp. You probably need to keep them as character.

Comment: If I keep them as a character, there is no way to plot them that doesn't require ranking them, right?

Comment: Yes, you need to create another variable for plotting, and use your vector for labeling.

Comment: Convert them all to a numeric representation of hours, e.g. hours + mins/60 + secs/3600. You could then plot as numeric. Or get fancy and convert them to a `difftime`

Answer (score 2):

Read the character times into a data.frame, `hms`, with columns `h`, `m` and `s` and then compute the number and fraction of days for each.  Finally plot your data vs. days:

```
# test data in character form
ch <- c("76:12:49", "74:11:32", "62:39:26", "57:17:17", "43:10:59", "29:06:00", "21:32:30", "16:00:36", "13:31:27", "9:55:12", "9:30:34")

hms <- read.table(text = ch, sep = ":", col.names = c("h", "m", "s"))
days <- with(hms, h / 24 + m / (24 * 60) + s / (24 * 60 * 60))
plot(seq_along(days) ~ days, ylab = "")
```

If hours are preferred then:

```
hours <- 24 * days
plot(seq_along(hours) ~ hours, ylab = "")
```

To get nicer day/times create a custom axis:

```
library(chron)

plot(seq_along(days) ~ days, ylab = "", xaxt = "n")
at <- axTicks(1)
axis(1, at = at, paste(at %/% 1, times(at %% 1)), cex.axis = .8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. I know how to plot the data in hours or days or minutes .  I was hoping to plot them in their format.